# Assigning to an Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

Why doesn't this very code work and what would be a solution?

In the function mentioned below in the code I'm trying to assign all values generated by that function to an array, creating somewhat of an easier form of a loop with **int o**. (because to start assigning from the beggining of an array, non of the loops above can be used)

Program crashes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{

int i;
int s;
int o;
int n;
n=20;
long int arr[n];
long int arr2[n];



for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    arr[i]=(i+1)*6;

}

//this function seems to do problems
o=0;
for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){
    for(s=1; s<n-i-1; s++){
        arr2[o]=arr[i+s]-arr[i]; o++;
    }
}




    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please EDIT YOUR QUESTION using the `edit` button just below the tags, and give us a hint on just what it is you're seeing. Error messages? Expected results vs. actual results? Wrong color? ???

Comment: @BobJarvis As I have said, program just crashes with no output.

Comment: This program produces no output. How can you tell it crashed?

Comment: Can you tell us what you want to calculate actually? what you want to put in arr2?

Comment: "*what would be a solution?*" to what? We do not even know the requirements? This is not a guessing game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It crashes because of this line:

```
 arr2[o]=arr[i+s]-arr[i]; o++;
```

In particular, the `o++` part. You're calling that inside a nested loop, so `o++` is going to be called more than `n` times, thus overflowing the buffer allocated for it.

`o` reaches 171 in this example - so you either need to make `arr2` large enough, or (more likely) move the `o++` to the outer loop.

Comment: I have also tried to make arra2 bigger, but seems like i underestimated it's length... n*10 seems to do fine, I just now have to check printed values.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to put o++ in outer loop because then instead of making inner loop he could just put:
arr2[o++] = arr[n - 2] - arr[i];

Comment: Could I? That seems reasonable. Thanks.

Comment: you could actually even remove variable o if this is your aim and just put:
for(i=0; i<n-1; i++){ arr2[i] = arr[n - 2] - arr[i]; }